# Why aren't my buttons aligning

Tags: asp.net, html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Menu.aspx.cs" Inherits="Menu" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Menu.css" type="text/css" />

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="position:absolute; margin: 0px; width:100%; height:100%;">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="text-align:center">
    <p id="userID">User ID</p>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div id="content" style="text-align:center; position:relative;">
<asp:Button text="MS Walking Scale Test" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Button Text="Get Results" runat="server"/>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" style="top:80%; position:relative;" Text="LogOut" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screen shot of Page]

Why are my buttons not evenly centred?

Comment: Why not include the actual code from the first image?

Comment: Where did you learn to align html elements like this? Just curious...

Comment: self taught. I'm and iOS developer mainly, but have to build this very basic site, needless to say I'm a little rusty. So any input you have is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because the div is to short? [Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/y2w8j/) for an attempt to recreate the problem.[1](http://jsfiddle.net/y2w8j/)
The default style of buttons should display them inline. since the buttons don't cant be display their full size on one row they are broken and appear uncentered. You also should replace text-align center for the more common approach that aligns the div center.
and the buttons inline.

that could be done like this

I suggest that you use css instead of style attribute though.